# grid gets out of screen android

Tags: android, grid, screen

I created an application for my tablet. But I want to use the application also on my mobile. The problem is that my grid gets out of screen. How can I make it to be always auto-sized?
It is just a part of my grid. I want to use the application for each devise.

my xmlcode:

```
       android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:gravity="top">
        <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="470px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImag"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/myscroll"
        android:scrollX="0dp"
        android:scrollY="0dp">
        <TableLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="172.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mytb"
            android:gravity="top">
            <TableRow
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                <TextView`enter code here`
                    android:id="@+id/mytb"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_width="162.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36.0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="187.5dp"
                android:layout_height="48.0dp">
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Code"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_width="105.7dp"
                    android:layout_height="34.0dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_width="73.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Age"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_width="80.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="23.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:text="Real nr"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="92.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="35.0dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="117.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <Button
            android:text="quit"
            android:id="@+id/quit"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:layout_width="101.3dp"
            android:layout_height="41.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.8dp" />
        <Button
            android:text="go "
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="144.0dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quit"
            android:layout_height="41.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="446.3dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:gravity="top">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="470px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImag"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:id="@+id/myscroll"
        android:scrollX="0dp"
        android:scrollY="0dp">
        <TableLayout
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="172.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mytb"
            android:gravity="top">
            <TableRow
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mytb"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_width="162.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36.0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="187.5dp"
                android:layout_height="48.0dp">
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Code"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_width="105.7dp"
                    android:layout_height="34.0dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />
                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:maxLength="20"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_width="73.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="36.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp" />
                   <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Age"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_width="80.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="23.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />
                    <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:text="Real nr"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:id="@+id/myt"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="92.0dp"
                    android:layout_height="35.0dp"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="117.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
         <Button
            android:text="quit"
            android:id="@+id/quit"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            android:layout_width="101.3dp"
            android:layout_height="41.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.8dp" />
          <Button
             android:text="go"
             android:id="@+id/save"
             android:layout_width="144.0dp"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quit"
             android:layout_height="41.5dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="446.3dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does your layout xml have hard coded width ?? use match_parent / wrap_content

Comment: yes,I set maximum and minimum width for each column ,in code.

Comment: you have to use dimen.xml for different resolution for height width and set them accordingly.

Comment: Are you using a `GridView`, `GridLayout` or what? Post some code.

Comment: post .xml file you're using and I will gladly fix it for you... regards

Comment: I post my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just take care of your xml item layout. Use wrap_content or match_parent to your TextView. it will manage itself.